# Best practice regarding encapsulation and single responsibility design

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I've been developing for many years and a common problem I face is how best to separate out the service layer. I've been using the repository pattern mainly, but I still struggle with this common scenario.

Customer service that returns a single customer.
Invoice service that returns a list of invoices by customer.

The consumer of the service sometimes wants just a Customer other times they want the customer and the invoices which is fine to leave as two calls.

But a new requirement may be they want the Customer, but also want the total number of invoices the respective customer has.

I do not want to corrupt the GetCustomer method and do not want to return a list of invoices and have them do a count (this would work). Is there a best practice without getting into create a lot of one of methods while still keeping performance and round trips in mind? I see a lot of designs where there will get GetCustomer, GetCustomerDeepLoad, etc.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Don't overthink it.

Services need to meet the needs of the clients. If the client wants customer details, the service sends a representation of customer details and nothing more; if the client wants a customer and all their orders, the service obliges; and so on. In doing so, you might need more than just a `Customer` object; for example, you might need a `CustomerOrderList` object made up of `CustomerOrderItem`, etc.

What you MUST NOT do is mix the concerns of order management and customer management, meaning that the `CustomerOrderItem` that you return will be a version suited for customer management and not the full-fledged `OrderItem` that would be modelled for order management.

Answer (score 0):

That's the reason why I have switched to CQRS. Operations (writing/commands) often targets a single entity type while reads (queries) often want a composition of entities.

You dont want to get those queries into the repositories as the repositories tend to get leaky abstractions when you do that.

In your case you can have two types of services: Entity services which are responsible of taking care of changes and query services which are responsible of taking care of supplying information to the client (composition of different entities).

I typically use repositories only on the write side and let the query services query the database directly. That works as you have your business logic contained in the entity services.

Comment: I like that. Do you have  naming convention you have found that works well?